# How to display dateTime relative to the user location?

Tags: symfony, twig

I am searching how to display the dateTime related to the user timezone using TWIG.
I really want to understand how it works.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy solution to get the user location in twig templates.
I would :

- Try to [get the user's timezone with Javascript](http://blog.codez.in/php5-time-zone-solution/web-development/2010/07/09)
- [Store this value in a session](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/controller.html#managing-the-session)
- Then catch it with twig fron the `{{ app.session }}` object

Good luck ;)

Comment: Yes, Thank you, I extended the Twig Date Filter function, then i add a parameter to be able to add the timezone in the date filter.